# PTIJ: Infinity - Mi Yodeya?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

### Who knows infinity?

### ?אין סוף - מי יודע

[Breishit 41:49](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=540&hilite=) says that when Yosef gathered grain to prepare for the upcoming famine in Egypt, he gathered so much that he stopped counting because there was no number.

It seems that Yosef was attempting to count to infinity but couldn't get there so he stopped somewhere just before it.

Other than Yosef's attempt, please cite other interesting Jewish facts about infinity that you can think of.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Can one truly ever know the Ein Sof?

Comment: Sounds like a question for a Kabbalist.

Comment: @rosends There's no end to the various answers to that question.

Comment: I don't see how this satisfies the "distinctly 'Purim'" criterion of the Purim Torah policy.

Comment: @msh210 absolutely, see https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/2746367/jewish/Infinity-in-Torah-and-Mathematics.htm which is quite serious.  That being said, there is precedent to leave it open: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80809/irrational-numbers-mi-yodeya?rq=1

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of Echad - Mi Yodeya? to me.

Comment: Corroboration of the point I just made (and Jews have been making since the beginning of history), by mathematicians no less: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Comment: As the Talmud says, ein ledavar sof -- There is no end to the matter.