# Shisha Va-arba'im Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty six?

### ששה וארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 346? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 346, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Together, we we shall build for Hashem my G-d a list of numbers on this mi-yodeya series the likes of which the world has never seen since the days of Elisha. Please refrain from lazy gematrias.

Comment: I thought only Isaac Moses was in charge of this. Did you take over for him?

Comment: @DanF I thought that since there hasn't been one since April, that it was time that we moved on with this.

Comment: I don't think that's any problem. It's been a while since I last viewed one of these numerical questions. I don't recall if Isaac had awarded "bounty" points for the best answer.

Comment: "the likes of which the world has never seen since the days of Elisha" - OK, I'm curious ... what did Elisha do with numbers?

Comment: @DanF אלישה is one of the nations mentioned in Genesis, and this seems to be the spelling that works

Comment: @DanF I never claimed or desired exclusive control of this series.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Oh well. :)

Comment: Why do you limit this to natural numbers? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80809/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69151/

Comment: @DonielF As you can see, the two questions (one of them, I asked,) are "Purim Torah". I know that Hashem has great imagination far beyond anything humans can imagine, but, I think only HE understands the "rational" behind imaginary numbers. As for irrational numbers, I'm afraid that many of our enemies consider Jews exactly that. It begs why I asked my question last year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Days in a normal year (כסדרה) one is allowed to eat חמץ (chutz l'aretz).
Full days (including Erev Pesach)  in a normal year (כסדרה) one is allowed to eat חמץ (Eretz Yisroel).

Answer (score 6):

In Israel, a normal year (Non-leap year / *kesdira*) has 346 days that are **not** a Yom Tov. The math details:

A normal *kesidra* year has 354 days

- 2 days Pesach
- 1 day Shavuot
- 2 days Rosh Hashanna
- 1 day Yom Kippur
- 1 day Succot
- 1 day Shmini Atzeret

8 days total; 354 - 8 = 346.

Comment: Work is forbidden on Shabbat

Comment: @DoubleAA Of course it is! Is my question unclear by specifically stating not a "Yom Tov"? I mean, I know that Shabbat is a *mo'ed*.

Comment: You defined a Yom Tov as a day off here work is forbidden

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess something isn't clear. I was narrowing my question to specifically Yom Tov which Shabbat is not. However, my thinking was that some people may think of all 8 days of Pesach as "Yom Tov", I said "days when work is forbidden" and followed that by stating excluding Hol Hamo'ed. I **thought** that clarified all the criteria.

Comment: "days when work is forbidden" includes Shabbat, Yom Tov, and Chol HaMoed. Work is forbidden on all of those.

Answer (score 6):

Once every 28 years we make a special Bracha when the sun returns to its original location. 28 Jewish years will generally have 346 months. Every 19 years has 7 additional months and the 9 additional years will generally have 3 additional months.

19 x 12 = 228 + 7 = 235

9 x 12 = 108 + 3 = 111

235 + 111 = 346 months

Comment: But we don't make it on the same day every 28 years (on the Jewish calendar) so there could be more or fewer complete months

Comment: In general it will work out to 346 Jewish months.

Comment: More accurately, 28 years are 28*365.25=10227 days. Averaging at 29.5 days per lunar month, there are 10227/29.5=346.67 months in a Machzor Gadol.

Comment: FYI, there is an intersting web site published by Remy Landau (Google his name, you should be able to find it) that explains why we wish people who celebrate their birthday *You should live for 120 LONG years." The article explains how the year you're born can possibly add up to about extra month in your 120-year life.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in [Menachos 43:](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9665&st=&pgnum=86&hilite=) says that King David was in the bathhouse and when he took off his Tzitzis he was disappointed that he was naked from Mitzvos. When he remembered that he has a Bris he was happy.

[Maharach Ohr Zarua Chapter 11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=997&st=&pgnum=25) mentioning this story of King David says that Milah is a Mitzva at every moment.

Based on this a child that is born in a year that has 353 days will have the Mitzva of Bris for 346 days in the first year of his life.

Answer (score -4):

Three hundred and forty six (346) is represented in Hebrew as שמ״ו, which is literally *His name*.

Like with all names, they are not the actual *being and essence* [(מהות ועצמות)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16082&hilite=935366e0-ddb8-4685-bfb2-45e394144c16&st=%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%95%D7%AA) of the one represented by the name. Yet, the name is intrinsically bound to that essence. In the language of Chassidut, [*Name* is only intended as a kind of handle for *another*](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19855&st=&pgnum=155) and that handle is [the means for the *other* to grasp and to connect to the *Essence* associated with that name](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19855&st=&pgnum=355&hilite=).

In [traditional Torah related abbreviations](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34968&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=), 346 (שמ״ו) is the abbreviation for *Heavens and Earth* (שמים וארץ).

And it is in this context that 346 teaches us many important principles in the Torah.

Bereshit 14:19

> וַיְבָרְכֵהוּ וַיֹּאמַר בָּרוּךְ אַבְרָם לְאֵל עֶלְיוֹן קֹנֵה שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ׃

We learn that the blessing of Malkitzedek, who was King of Shalem and Priest to G-d above, was that Avram was blessed to G-d above, *owner* of *Heaven and Earth*.

And this follows the teaching found in Mishlei 3:19

> יְהוָה בְּחָכְמָה יָסַד־אָרֶץ כּוֹנֵן שָׁמַיִם בִּתְבוּנָה׃

That G-d founded the Earth with wisdom and established the Heavens with understanding. And through this process, they became His possession, [like Rashi teaches](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.14.19.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi).

And just as the blessings of Avram came from the Owner of Heaven and Earth, so too, this is the source of our blessings as found in Tehillim 115:15

> בְּרוּכִים אַתֶּם לַיהוָה עֹשֵׂה שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ׃

In addition to this referring to the One who blesses us, it also reminds us that G-d is the one who helps us, both individually, like in Tehillim 121:2,

> עֶזְרִי מֵעִם יְהוָה עֹשֵׂה שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ׃

and collectively, like in Tehillim 124:8.

> עֶזְרֵנוּ בְּשֵׁם יְהוָה עֹשֵׂה שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ׃

And it is taught from Midrash Mishlei 31:5 that if we are engaged in Torah day and night, G-d counts it for us as if we are partners with Him in maintaining *Heaven and Earth*.

> אמר הקב"ה לישראל: בניי, היו מתעסקים בתורה ביום ובלילה, ומעלה אני עליכם
>   כאילו אתם מעמידין שמים וארץ, שנאמר (יהושע א ח): "לא ימוש ספר התורה הזה
>   מפיך והגית בו יומם ולילה"

And this same sentiment is repeated by the prophet Jeremiah 33:25.

> כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה אִם־לֹא בְרִיתִי יוֹמָם וָלָיְלָה חֻקּוֹת שָׁמַיִם וָאָרֶץ לֹא־שָׂמְתִּי׃

And 346, through this phrase *Heavens and Earth*, also reminds us of the final redemption like is referenced in Tehillim 134:3

> יְבָרֶכְךָ֣ יְ֭הוָה מִצִּיּ֑וֹן עֹ֝שֵׂ֗ה שָׁמַ֥יִם וָאָֽרֶץ׃

And it also teaches us about the World to Come like in Isaiah 65:17.

> כִּי־הִנְנִי בוֹרֵא **שָׁמַיִם** חֲדָשִׁים **וָאָרֶץ** חֲדָשָׁה וְלֹא תִזָּכַרְנָה הָרִאשֹׁנוֹת וְלֹא תַעֲלֶינָה עַל־לֵב׃

And all of this is directed toward the unification of Heaven and Earth to reveal His Oneness like is expressed by Ramban to Shemot 20:13:1.

> שתי לוחות כנגד **שמים וארץ** וכנגד חתן וכלה וכנגד שני שושבינין וכנגד שני עולמים. *וכל זה רמז* **אחד**, והמשכיל יבין הסוד:

That just as the two tablets of the law are one, so too, Heaven and Earth are one, Bridegroom and Bride are one, Moshe and Aharon (*the two Escorts*) are one and this world and the World to Come are one.

And this sentiment is what was expressed by Zecharia 14:9.

> וְהָיָ֧ה יְהוָ֛ה לְמֶ֖לֶךְ עַל־כָּל־הָאָ֑רֶץ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֗וּא יִהְיֶ֧ה יְהוָ֛ה אֶחָ֖ד וּשְׁמ֥וֹ אֶחָֽד׃

And the L-rd shall be king over all the earth; in that day the L-rd will be one **and** *His name* (שמ״ו) one.

Comment: To quote the OP (and the other 345 questions in this series): “No lazy gematrias.”

Comment: @DonielF There is no mention of gematria in my answer whatsoever. However, it should be noted that the last paragraph in the question, which you are referencing, was not in  the original question. It was added by someone else after an answer had been provided. According to site guidelines, modifying questions after answers have been provided is prohibited.

Comment: Gematria is always forbidden by this sequence of questions. And your first line is “346 is represented in Hebrew as שמו, which is literally *His name.*” That’s just a fancy way of saying that the gematria of שמו is 346.

Comment: @DonielF No, it’s recognizing that Hebrew represents numbers via the letters of the Aleph-Beit. That is not gematria, the concept that Hebrew words with equivalent numerical values are related ideas. If you or anyone else wants to complain, at least be accurate in your criticism. Any downvotes on this basis come from ignorance and prejudice.

Comment: @doniel you're right of course but it's probably not worth arguing back

Comment: @YaacovDeane Just out of curiosity, what do _you_ think the OP meant to exclude in a question about the significance of a certain number by disallowing gematrias?

Comment: @Yez I will repeat that the original posted question by the OP did not include the last paragraph. I would not presume to know the intent of the individual who added that paragraph. However, it should be noted that throughout the series, the qualified phrase used is “lazy gematria”. Which is even more irrelevant because there is no such term in Torah. It doesn’t mean gematria itself, a legitimate form of Torah interpretation used by such giants as the Rokeach & Rabbi Yehuda HaChassid. I believe Isaac Moses may have been the 1st to use it. Perhaps you should ask him what it means.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I am not sure why you feel you need Rishonim to justify gematria - the Talmud itself uses gematria. "Lazy gematria" has been a term used for several years now in this series with a pretty clear context. I can't imagine not understanding what it means without a healthy dose of willful ignorance. (I'll also note that, unlike your repeated assertion, the original question also had the gematria disclaimer, just formulated slightly differently.)